# Android how to ignore "the" while sorting?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am already using the "Where" clause to ignore the songs with size less than 10 secs,
by using the following code, but I don't know how to ignore "the" in titles.
Also, how can I use two "where" clauses?

```java
String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
            Cursor songCursor = getActivity().managedQuery
            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, TRACK_COLUMNS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 10000", null, sortOrder);
```

## Edit:on request,full code

```java
public class F_Songs extends Fragment implements Serializable {
    DynamicListView SngList; private DisplayMetrics metrics;  
    ArrayList<SongDetails> songdetails = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
    String[] TRACK_COLUMNS;Cursor songCursor = null;


    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    ViewGroup view;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.l_songs, null);
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();  
   // getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 

     TRACK_COLUMNS = new String[] {          
             MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM,
             MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
             MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
             MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
             MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION,
             MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TRACK,
             MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.YEAR, 
             MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE,
             MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID
             };
            String sortOrder =//"REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", ' <BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>')"+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC"; 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
            Cursor songCursor = getActivity().managedQuery
            (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, TRACK_COLUMNS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 10000", null, sortOrder); 
            if(songCursor != null){
            while(songCursor.moveToNext()) {
            SongDetails songs = new SongDetails();
            songs.song= songCursor.getString(8);
            songs.Path=songCursor.getString(2);
            songs.Album=songCursor.getString(0);
            songs.Artist=songCursor.getString(1);

            try{    
                int intTime = Integer.parseInt(songCursor.getString(4));
                int newTime=intTime/1000;
                int newTimeMinutes=newTime/60;
                int newTimeSeconds=newTime%60;
                String max2;

        if(newTimeSeconds<10){
        max2=newTimeMinutes+":0"+newTimeSeconds;
        }
        else{
        max2=newTimeMinutes+":"+newTimeSeconds;
        }
        songs.Time=max2;
        }   
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        songdetails.add(songs);}
        }

        SngList = (DynamicListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        registerForContextMenu(SngList);
      /*    String uri = "android.resource://" + this.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.ro;
            SongDetails songs = new SongDetails();
        songs.setPath2( uri) ;
        songs.setSong("ro");
        songdetails.add(songs); 

        uri = "android.resource://" + this.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.same_high;
            songs = new SongDetails();
            songs.setPath2( uri) ;
            songs.setSong("same_high");
            songdetails.add(songs); 
   */



        SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlaying.class);
                 intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1",songdetails);
                 intent.putExtra("Data2",position);
                 startActivity(intent);
                       }  
                 });

        SngList.setCheeseList(songdetails);
        SngList.setAdapter(new Adapter_ListView(songdetails));



        SngList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        //getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        return view;
        }}
```

Comment: NOT LIKE"%the%" could be of the option if you don't want that whole record and that will return only those record which doesn't contains THE.

Comment: no i don't want that...i just want "the" to be ignored while sorting.... e.g i have a list...

1.)Ankit
2.)Bombay
3.)The Ankit
4.)The Bombay


after sorting

1.)Ankit
2.)The Ankit
3.)Bombay
4.)The Bombay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use REPLACE to remove "The" from text.
For two "where" claused, just join their expressions using boolean operators (AND or OR):

```
sortOrder = "REPLACE (" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ", 'The', '') COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
Cursor songCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    TRACK_COLUMNS,
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 10000 AND " + 
       MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE '%summer%'", 
    null, 
    sortOrder);
```

Update (worked for Ankit, following comments below):

```
String sortOrder ="REPLACE ('<BEGIN>' || " +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", '<BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>')"+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
```

Comment: tried this
String sortOrder ="REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", ' <BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>') COLLATE NOCASE ASC"; 
       

and this 

       String sortOrder ="REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", 'The ', '') COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

but didn't help

Comment: Note that your first sortOrder from above is different from that in the other answer and will not work for sure. The second sortOrder looks ok to me. Are you sure it didn't work? Do you have rows with the "the" in title? Can you provide an output example?

Comment: yeah mann it remained the same..........i am sure about it......is their any problem with quotes and double quotes ??(just guessing)?

Comment: None that I notice. What is the exact value of MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE ?

Comment: well anyways thanx for your time nd ur try +1 for that,if u come up with an answer i would be very grateful :)

Comment: If you're willing to share your code, please do and I can review it further.

Comment: If you tried the sortOrder commented out in code it's normal it doesn't work as it's missing some parts and has extra spaces. Try this:
String sortOrder ="REPLACE ('<BEGIN>' || " +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", '<BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>')"+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41871/discussion-between-andrei-b-and-ankit-srivastava)

Answer (score 2):

You could sort by:

```
REPLACE (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, 'The ', '')
```

If `The` should only in front of the title use for instance:

```
REPLACE ('<BEGIN>' || MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, '<BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>')
```

This is rather an outline ... hope it helps though :)

Comment: please explain it a bit...i am already using a sort order so how should i merge (ur sort order with mine) and what is your code  actually doing ??is it replacing the text or what?please explain ??i just don't want to copy paste

Comment: The intention of my code is to remove the String `The ` while ordering. You don't need to merge the sort orders just use `String sortOrder = "REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", 'The ', '') COLLATE NOCASE ASC";` for instance.

Comment: tried this
String sortOrder ="REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", ' <BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>') COLLATE NOCASE ASC"; 
       

and this 

       String sortOrder ="REPLACE (" +MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE +", 'The ', '') COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

but didn't help

Comment: Ah, now I see it - you missed the first `'BEGIN' ||` before `+MediaStore` - but I see you got some help ... :)

Comment: Your welcome, I'm happy to help. Just was too blind this Monday morning and didn't saw it right away ;) Thx

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it'll work in your case. try to use built-in function of sqlite **"replace()"**

**Example:**

```
Select title= replace( title, 'the', '' ) from  table  WHERE title LIKE '%the%';
```

Hope this will work, Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have try this and working perfectly as you want.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN user_NAME LIKE '%the%' 
    THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(user_NAME, INSTR(user_NAME,' '))) 
    ELSE user_NAME  
    END
```

- Apple
- The Apple
- Boy
- The Boy
- Cat
- The Cat

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE test SET phares = replace(phares, 'the', ' ');
```